# "(both)/(either) only available to men (and)/(or) women under pension age"

Tags: ambiguity

Let us suppose we are writing a legal document in which it must be stated that benefit are available to:

(1)  men under pension age;

(2)  women under pension age.

Which of the following best describes that statement?

> (1.a)  There are three types of bereavement benefit that are available only
>   to men and women under pension age.
>
> (1.b)  There are three types of bereavement benefit that are available only to men or women under pension age.
>
> (2.a)  There are three types of bereavement benefit that are available only both to men and women under pension age.
>
> (2.b)  There are three types of bereavement benefit that are available only either to men or women under pension age.

Comment: You could try _people under pension age_ unless there are some possibilities other than _men_ or _women_ you wish to exclude.

Comment: @BrianHooper the specific legal context constrains people to recognize that difference.

Comment: @Chrétien Chevalier: That sounds like nonsense to me. In what possible legal context can you be constrained to specify *men and women* as distinct from *people*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers "People under pension age" could elicit the question "Which pension age? Men's or women's?" Andrew Leach said.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree that *people* would almost always be adequate, but it is conceivable (if not probable) that someone might think the rules applied only to men or women. In that case, stating both, rather than *people* might clarify.

Comment: @FumbleFingers After bib's and Andrew's comments I would vote down both your comment and Hooper'comment! But I cannot.

Comment: In a legal document, another catch to using the word "people" is that it is often used in legal contexts to include fictional persons like corporations. That may or may not apply here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers After Jay's comment, I see entirely the nonsense of your assertion.

Comment: @Chrétien Chevalier: I'm sorry you feel that way, but so far as I'm concerned, ELU should be concerned with standard *English* usage, not legalese.

Comment: Also, *that are* is unnecessary here and so unhelpful (or *surplusage* as legalese has it).

Comment: @Jay - Unless there were a specific section of the legal document that defined *people* to include corporations (and I cannot remember having seen this in 25 yrs of reviewing and writing legal docs, recent politcal speeches notwithstanding), the term *person* is the routinely used word that may include corporations or other non-human entities.

Comment: @bib I'm not sure if you're agreeing with me or disagreeing. In any case, I've read text of laws where it was apparent that "person" did include corporations, and a few that carefully distinguished "natural persons". And I'm reminded of a court case I read years ago where a man was convicted of "conspiracy" under a law that defined conspiracy as "three or more persons" planning a crime. The "three persons" were him, his business partner, and the corporation that the two of them had created.

Comment: @Jay - I am agreeing with the concept, but I think the term used is almost always *person* rather than *people*.

Comment: @bib Ah, I didn't catch the distinction you were making. You may well be right: IANAL, I must admit I haven't studied the wording that carefully.

Comment: @Jay and to keep the stilted legal language going, we use *persons* for the plural rather than *people*, which is what real humans (people-persons) would say.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I would write it this way:

> There are three types of bereavement benefit that are available only to men under pension age and women under pension age.

(Notes: I think you want *that* and no comma. I also think you want to place *only* after available. I'm not sure why you have *usually* in your examples, because your initial statement doesn't seem to have that sense.)

Comment: +1 This caters for the possibility that men and women have different pension ages; and it avoids the ambiguity of "available only to men or women under pension age" which could be read as "available only to men, or women under pension age" (note the comma). "People under pension age" could elicit the question "Which pension age? Men's or women's?"

Comment: I corrected the statements, so you can delete your notes.

Answer (score 2):

I find that separating broad statements from each other, using coordinating rather than subordinating constructions, provides a structure in which it is easier to make clear just what a particular subordinated qualification refers to.

Before I offer an example, it needs to be noted that there are two ambiguities in your versions:

- It is not clear what *usually* and *only* modify. I'm assuming that *only* modifies *under pension age* and that *usually* modifies *only* (that is, occasionally these benefits may be extended to older men and women)
- Your comma implies that *which are available &c* is non-restrictive, and I'm assuming that that is the case; but as JLG suggests, you may intend a restrictive use—that is, that there are more than three types of bereavement benefit, of which three are available only to &c

Under those assumptions, I would write something like this:

> There are three types of bereavement leave; all three are available to both men and women, but [usually] only to those under pension age.

In my opinion, breaking the first two statements paratactically like this makes it easier for the writer  to control—and the reader to follow.

Comment: If in this document you frequently refer to "both men and women", you might add some definitions up front, e.g. define "participant" to be "any man or woman covered under this plan" or whatever, and then use this term. This is common in legal documents precisely because of this problem.

Comment: @Jay   Quite true. However, it is not always convenient for employees to read a policy or benefit manual from beginning to end in order to discover their privileges and responsibilities with respect to a single matter; so language which is legally effective and concise may not be the best way of informing the people involved. And lawyers are not always as conscientious as they  should be. I once spent three months rewriting, for intelligibility in 2005, a complicated employment contract which had been drafted (barely adequately) in the 1940s and revised (badly) in the 1960s and 1980s.

Comment: Sure. And I'm not disagreeing with your suggestion above. I guess I'm just trying to say that being readable and being precise are often contradictory goals. One solution is to be wordier, like your suggestion. Another is to establish definitions up front and rely on them. I'm sure there are other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as:

> There are three types of bereavement benefit that are available only to men and women under **their** pension age.

Note the word I added. This would make it more explicit that each man or woman has their own pension age, and thus would not necessarily group everyone under the same pension age.

Comment: *Their* is plural, so it would have to be *...under their respective pension ages*.

Answer (score 0):

*Only both* is so confusing as to be wrong; beyond that, it's a matter of style, and how far you want legal precision to take precedence over comprehensibility.  But for what it's worth, I would phrase it "There are three types of benefit available only to recipients under pension age", assuming that *members* is not appropriate.